# How to get lat/lng from a geo-autocomplete object and google api V2?

Tags: autocomplete, geocoding, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to implements the geo-autocomplete with the jQuery, jquery.autocomplete_geomod and geo_autocomplete plugins and the Google Maps API V2.

In parallel, we're migrating to the V3, so don't be scared to say that my problem is due to the version 2.

So, I need the lat/long returned by the autocomplete, to center my map on this coordinates... but I didn't success to do that !

There's a part of my code. Don't hesitate to ask me questions.

```
$().ready(function() {

    var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var loc = $('#location').geo_autocomplete(mygc, {
        mapkey: '<?$GOOGLE_KEY?>',
        ...
        geocoder_address: true

      }).result(function(_event, _data){
         //if(_data){
                    alert("test");
                    alert( "latitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() );
          //}
                   //alert( "longitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng() );
        });

    });
```

Regards,

Guillaume from France

Answer (score 1):

In `ui.geo_autocomplete.js` add a location variable `_location = _result.geometry.location` to the `_parsed` results.

Something like this:

```
_parsed.push({
    value: _place,
    label: _result.formatted_address,
    viewport: _result.geometry.viewport,
    location: _location
});
```

Then you can access it from `_ui.item.geometry.location`.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the `ui.geo_autocomplete.js` at line 73 with `location: _result.geometry.location`:

```
_parsed.push({
value: _place,
label: _result.formatted_address,
viewport: _result.geometry.viewport,
location: _result.geometry.location
 });
```

You can access these variable for example with the alert() method like this:

```
$('#stadt').geo_autocomplete({
    geocoder_region: 'Germany',
    geocoder_types: "locality,political,sublocality,neighborhood",
    mapheight: 100, mapwidth: 200, maptype: 'hybrid',
     select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.location);
    return false;
}

})
```